# React useEffect hook dependent on a second effect

Tags: reactjs, async-await, infinite-loop, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using a useEffect hook to asynchronously fetch data when my component initially mounts. I would also like to use an effect (or another hook that would be better suited for this situation) to transform these data, also when my component initially mounts.

**Reference context and initialize `enhancedSections` local state**

```
  const displayContext = useContext(DisplayContext);
  const { sections } = displayContext;

  const schemaContext = useContext(SchemaContext);
  const { schema, getSchema } = schemaContext;

  const [enhancedSections, setEnhancedSections] = React.useState(sections);
```

**Get data on mount (this works)**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await getSchema()
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

**Transform fetched data, and `setEnhancedSections`** 
*the problem here is that `schema` is still null at this point*

```
  useEffect(() => {
      let newSectionsArr = [];
      const schemaData = schema.data; //schema hasn't fetched yet
      Object.entries(sections).forEach(section => {
        let sectionKey = section[0];
        for(var i = 1; i < section.length; i++){
          section[i].forEach(item => {
            let table = schemaData.find(table => table[item.definition.table_name]);
            if (table) {
              let obj = table[item.definition.table_name].columns.find(column => column.field === item.definition.field_name);
              if (obj) {
                item.definition.description = obj.description;
                item.section = sectionKey;
                newSectionArr.push(item);
              }
            }
           setEnhancedSections(newSectionArr); // infinite loop...different problem
          });
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

When I pull the above out of useEffect and place into a basic if statement, it works (infinite loop still a problem)...

```
 if(schema && sections){
      let newSectionArr = [];
       ...
    }
```

I understand I should use multiple effects to separate concerns according to the React docs, but I'm not sure how to make one effect "await" another.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me know if my answer doesn't work. I'm pretty confident in it, but if it doesn't I have another idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part doesn't need to be in a `useEffect`, it's simply derived from your existing state. You're hitting an infinite loop because you're calling `setEnhancedState`, but `enhancedState` is derived and doesn't need to exist in state itself. Your final component may look something like this:

```
const displayContext = useContext(DisplayContext);
const { sections } = displayContext;

const schemaContext = useContext(SchemaContext);
const { schema, getSchema } = schemaContext;

// No need for redundant enhancedSections state

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    await getSchema()
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

let enhancedSections = [];
const schemaData = schema ? schema.data : [];
Object.entries(sections).forEach(section => {
  let sectionKey = section[0];
  for(var i = 1; i < section.length; i++){
    section[i].forEach(item => {
      let table = schemaData.find(table => table[item.definition.table_name]);
      if (table) {
        let obj = table[item.definition.table_name].columns.find(column => column.field === item.definition.field_name);
        if (obj) {
          item.definition.description = obj.description;
          item.section = sectionKey;
          enhancedSections.push(item);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

// Use enhancedSections as you need now
```

Comment: this solution still throws a "cannot read property of 'data' null", as ```fetchData()``` hasn't retrieved the schema data yet. If I wrap the for loop with ```if(schema){...}```, it works...but I didn't think a floating if statement was best practice.

Comment: @BWeb303 updated to do a quick check if schema exists first when assigning to `schemaData`... a ternary operator should be more palatable in this case.

Comment: the ternary operator worked. However, I do need to set ```enhancedSections``` as a local state variable bc it will be accessed/updated throughout the component. Where in/outside of this for loop would I ```setEnhancedSections``` to avoid the infinite loop? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does `enhancedSections` get modified? I only ask because if, for example, the modification is apply a filter or something like that, you can actually set the filter in state